# Matlab - dynamic indexing

Tags: matlab

In matlab, do I have to declare a matrix, and how do I do it? For example, can I do

```
function res = compute()
  res(1) = 1;
  res(2) = 2;
end
```

or do I have to declare res first?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to declare your matrices in matlab.  Your code will work.

It is generally faster if you preallocate memory using `ones` or `zeros` for your matrices.  Otherwise Matlab has to keep reallocating memory as the matrix changes size.

Example

```
% Slow
x(1) = 3; % x is now 1 by 1
x(5) = 9; % Matlab has to reallocate memory to increase x to be 1 by 5
x(10) = 2; % And another reallocation to increase x to be 1 by 10

% Better
y = zeros(1,10); % preallocate memory for the matrix
y(1) = 3;
y(5) = 9;
y(10) = 2;

% One-liner
z([1 5 10]) = [3 9 2]; % you can assign multiple values at once
```

Preallocation helps the most when you have to use loops

```
a = zeros(1,100)
for i=1:100
    a(i) = i^2;
end
```

Even better if you can vectorize code so you don't have to use a for loop

```
a = (1:100).^2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are many ways, you can start by first learning how to declare arrays [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Arrays).

In your case, it looks like you are trying to do something like:

`res = [1,2]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare the array/matrix. What you have right now will work.

You can always declare an empty matrix with `matrix = []`

Even crazier, you can do stuff like

```
a(2,3) = 7
```

resulting in

```
a =

     0     0     0
     0     0     7
```